# a class inheritance hierarchy design issue

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I have the following class hierarchy for graphs:

```
typedef vector<int> ArrayI;
typedef vector<Array<long>> Mat2DB;
typedef vector<ArrayI> adjList;

class baseGraph {
    int nodes;
    ArrayI degree;
    //some member functions.
}

class matGraph: public baseGraph {
    Mat2DB matrix;
    //member functions.
}

class lMatGraph: public matGraph {
    ArrayI labels;
    //member functions.
}

class listGraph: public baseGraph {
    adjList list;
    //member functions.
}

class lListGraph: public listGraph {
    ArrayI labels;
    //member functions.
}
```

Now in this class I have many other functions, mostly virtual, so that when I get to call the proper function while using the base class pointer.

For example I have a function `sssp(int node)` which implements single source shortest path. The implementation are both different for `class matGraph` and `class listGraph` which are adjacency matrix representation and adjacency list representation of graphs respectively. Now there is not need to change the definition for labelled version of these graphs so I do not define these functions again in `lListGraph` and `lMatGraph`

Now the only problem I am havin is with `setLabel(const ArratI &)` in `lListGraph` and `lMatGraph` classes. I need this function to be virtual so that it gets called through base class pointer, but at the same time I do not have anything such as labels for classes `matGraph` and `listGraph`.

I do not know if my design hierarchy is correct or not, but it seemed intuitive to me. So any comments on that would be good. What can I do with the `setLabel` function. Is it okay to have such a function(to me it looks like kind of a workaround so this question) or do I need to reconsider my class hierarchy.

P.S.: I would also love if there are some books from which I can practice design questions like these. I run into these delimma offten and am not sure what to do of them.

EDIT:

Use of class graph is used in another class `clustering` where I have a member `baseGraph *graph`  i.e.

```
class clustering {
    baseGraph *graph;
}
```

I am storing the pointer to base class here so that I can use the different algorithms(implemented as functions) from `class graph`. For clustering class it again depends what type of graph I want to use.

Comment: Do remember that `vector<bool>` is specialized to be different from all other standard containers (you may have intended this).

Comment: @MarkB In my orginal implementation I am using `vector<int>` to model the weighted graphs so it is fine, but glad to know the difference. While typing the question I thought to make the hierarchy simple. I will edit the question.

Comment: Does the label need to be able to change multiple times at runtime? Or will it remain constant for the life of the object?

Comment: @MarkB For a graph it will remain constant for the runtime, once set.To add more, it may be that I do not have the label at the time of construction and I have to set them after the object is constructed.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this ?

```
typedef vector<int> ArrayI;
typedef vector<Array<long>> Mat2DB;
typedef vector<ArrayI> adjList;

class baseGraph {
    int nodes;
    ArrayI degree;
    virtual void sssp(int node);
    //some member functions.
}

class labeledGraph: public virtual baseGraph {
    ArrayI labels;
    virtual void setLabel(const ArratI &);
    //member functions.
}

class matGraph: public virtual baseGraph {
    Mat2DB matrix;
    //member functions.
}

class lMatGraph: public virtual matGraph, public virtual labeledGraph {
    //member functions.
}

class listGraph: public virtual baseGraph {
    adjList list;
    //member functions.
}

class lListGraph: public virtual listGraph, public virtual labeledGraph {
    //member functions.
}
```

I'm assuming here that you incorrectly inherited from graph when you should have been inheriting from baseGraph (typeo) - though even if not it comes down to same point.

Also rough coding, if you have questions or if there are mistakes feel free to ask.

Comment: Sorry if this is naive, but I have never used virtual and multiple inheritance before. So could you please explain how will I get to call `setLabels` with `baseGraph` pointer.

Comment: If you _have_ to call it through `baseGraph*`, then there is no option but to have it on `class baseGraph`, in which case the other answers apply. For my suggestion you would be calling it through `labeledGraph*` - since it would make sense to work with `labelGraph*` when there is a possibility of setting labels.

Could you not rather make clustering a template ? `template < typename GraphType > clustering { /*...*/ std::unique_ptr< GraphType >* graph; }` ? in which case you could look at some options to test for existence of setLabel on the template type before proceeding to use it.

Comment: Earlier I didn't think of making clustering a template class, but now I am kind of starting to like the idea. The only problem I think I will get into is that if I needed to change my representation of graph(which is a possible case) during the course of my program then I will not be able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You say that `setLabel` should be called through base class pointer, so this necessarily means that it should be declared in the base class, even though it doesn't make sense. You can implement `setLabel` for graphs that are not labelled in two possible ways:

- Do nothing - just ignore the request for setting the labels
- Throw an exception (e.g. `abort`) - something is probably wrong, so the user should know that!

Each way is a workaround, so you should consider why `setLabel` should be called through base class pointer, and possibly change this decision. I'd expect, if you really need a labelled graph for your algorithm, use the appropriate type instead of a base-class type - then you don't need to do any hacks to the base class.

Note that if you keep adding stuff to the base class that corresponds to each derived class, you are going to end up with [a lot of mess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_bloat) in the base class - no good!

---

In addition, the following may solve your problem with `setLabel` and make your class hierarchy "healthier".

Consider moving your basic algorithms like `sssp` away from the class declarations - make them overloaded free-standing functions instead of member functions. This way you won't need to declare `sssp` in the base class either. If you adopt this guideline, when you implement a new algorithm, the compiler will check all function calls, and issue an error if one is missing (this is better than a crash or getting incorrect results).

```
class baseGraph {
    int nodes;
    ArrayI degree;
    // a minimum number of member functions (e.g. getNode; getEdges)
}

class matGraph: public graph {
    Mat2DB matrix;
}

class lMatGraph: public matGraph {
    ArrayI labels;
    void setLabel(const ArrayI &);
}

int sssp(const matGraph& graph, int node)
{
    // Some code
}

int sssp(const lMatGraph& graph, int node)
{
    // Some code; here you can use labels
}
```

This is discussed in the Effective C++ book ([Effective C++ Item 23 Prefer non-member non-friend functions to member functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989734/effective-c-item-23-prefer-non-member-non-friend-functions-to-member-functions))

Comment: I have edited the question to add some more details. The point is if I have non member function then the clustering class will be a total mess up because I have to take care of every graph-type on my own.

Answer (score 0):

It all boils down to a simple choice. What should happen if I try to set a label in a graph that does not in fact support labels?

1. Nothing (the attempt may be logged but is otherwise ignored)
2. A catastrophic failure
3. I should not be able to even try (the compiler should not let me)

That's it. These are all your options.

The first two options are easy, you just write a virtual function that reports an error (logs it, or throws an exception).

The third one is interesting. It means there is no corresponding virtual function at all. Not in your class and not in any base class. This goes against your design but your design is not necessarily perfect.

So how do you set a label then? Through something that is not a pointer to your base class :) It can be a pointer to another base class (a mixin ― you use multiple inheritance to add labeling functionality to graphs). Or you may templatize your design so that the hierarchy does not really matter and you always statically know the most derived type of your objects.