# Concise way to write a for/else in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, for-else

In some code I was working on, I have a for loop that iterates through a map:

```
for (auto it = map.begin(); it != map.end(); ++it) {

    //do stuff here
}
```

And I wondered if there was some way to concisely write something to the effect of:

```
for (auto it = map.begin(); it != map.end(); ++it) {
    //do stuff here
} else {
    //Do something here since it was already equal to map.end()
}
```

I know I could rewrite as:

```
auto it = map.begin();
if (it != map.end(){

    while ( it != map.end() ){
        //do stuff here
        ++it;
    }

} else {
    //stuff
}
```

But is there a better way that doesn't involve wrapping in an if statement?

Comment: What's a `for() {} else {}` please?!?

Comment: No there's no way of doing it without a conditional wrapper of some sort.

Comment: It's a statement of python and other language that let you specify what happen when the loop is no executed any time.

Comment: You mean a Python-style `for else`?

Comment: I think something like this was proposed once.

Comment: Been a little bit since I did python, but yeah, basically a python for-else.

Comment: Well you could always switch to Ruby and do something like `for blah unless otherblah`

Comment: @sharth Ah, my mistake. I did a quick example in the python interpreter to check with an empty container in a for loop, but didn't realize the else would trigger even with a non-empty container.

Comment: Only because I dislike having the else block going first, I added [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27187956/2932052) that (kind-of) switches the Havenard blocks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Obviously...

```
if (map.empty())
{
    // do stuff if map is empty
}
else for (auto it = map.begin(); it != map.end(); ++it)
{
    // do iteration on stuff if it is not
}
```

By the way, since we are talking C++11 here, you can use this syntax:

```
if (map.empty())
{
    // do stuff if map is empty
}
else for (auto it : map)
{
    // do iteration on stuff if it is not
}
```

Comment: In general though, say for an object that doesn't have .empty(), is there a more concise way to for-else?

Comment: `if (map.begin() == map.end())`

Comment: `template<class R>bool empty(R const& r){using std::begin; using std::end; return begin(r)==end(r);}` is a `.empty()` that works on all iterable ranges.

Comment: Is this `else for`-condensed-into-one-line actually familiar to people? I mean sure it's clever and accomplishes its purpose, but I can't help but wonder if it's recognized enough to be as readable as an indented `for` on the next line.

Comment: @chris It's not idiomatic the way writing `} else if (...) {` in place of `} else { if (...) {` is, but it shouldn't confuse anyone who's vaguely familiar with C-like languages. On the other hand clang-format doesn't automatically format code this way so unless one wants to format code manually...

Comment: This isn't the same as a Python `else` since that executes if the container is empty, or it has been traversed through entirely.  The only time it doesn't execute is on a `break` statement.  See: https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

Comment: @KevinAnderson the question doesn't explicitly mention python, the intended behaviour is placed in a comment `//Do something here since it was already equal to map.end()`

Comment: @Wolf - True, but the original author mentions Python in a comment below his original question, and thus it's up to mention.  I do agree his original comment in the code is the most important.

Comment: Better would be `for (auto &&it : map)`: the way you have it, the map entry is copied by value to `it` for each loop iteration. In a range-based for loop, `it` is not actually an iterator; it's the value stored in the container. There is no way to access the underlying iterator.

Comment: You answer is quite impressive (as I already mentioned in SOspeak), it lead me to the [even more astonishing if-for-else control structure](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27187956/2932052) that is even valid C! But most programmers seem to be really shocked by such structural options.

Answer (score 5):

If you want more crazy control flow in C++, you can write it in C++11:

```
template<class R>bool empty(R const& r)
{
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  return begin(r)==end(r);
}
template<class Container, class Body, class Else>
void for_else( Container&& c, Body&& b, Else&& e ) {
  if (empty(c)) std::forward<Else>(e)();
  else for ( auto&& i : std::forward<Container>(c) )
    b(std::forward<decltype(i)>(i));
}

for_else( map, [&](auto&& i) {
  // loop body
}, [&]{
  // else body
});
```

but I'd advise against it.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [Havenard's `else for`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25208474/2932052), I tried this structure with the else part sitting in the right place <sup>[1]</sup>.

```
if (!items.empty()) for (auto i: items) {
    cout << i << endl;
} else {
    cout << "else" << endl;
}
```

> ([full demo](http://ideone.com/92eAOb))

I'm not sure if I would use it in real code, also because I do not remember a single case that I was missing an `else` clause for the `for` loop, but I've to admit that only today I learned that python has it. I read from your comment

```
//Do something here since it was already equal to map.end()
```

...that you are probably not referring to [python's `for-else`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops), but maybe you did - also [python programmers seem to have their problems with this feature](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2009-October/006155.html).

---

<sup>[1]</sup> unfortunately, there is no [concise opposite of is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21882655/2932052) in C++ ;-)