# Why is operator<< function between std::ostream and char a non-member function?

Tags: c++, c++11, ostream

When I ran the following program

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   char c = 'a';
   std::cout << c << std::endl;
   std::cout.operator<<(c) << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

I got the output

```
a
97
```

Digging further at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt, I noticed that `std::ostream::operator<<()` does not have an overload that has `char` as the argument type. The function call `std::cout.operator<<(a)` gets resolved to `std::ostream::operator<<(int)`, which explains the output.

I am assuming that the `operator<<` function between `std::ostream` and `char` is declared elsewhere as:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, char c);
```

Otherwise, `std::cout << a` would resolve to `std::ostream::operator<<(int)`.

My question is why is that declared/defined as a non-member function? Are there any known issues that prevent it from being a member function?

Comment: Maybe because of the character type template parameter? This function can have the same ("efficient") implementation for any character type by using the locale's `widen`.

Comment: Interesting topic. Might be a reason why [what was discussed here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31230237/enforcing-unsigned-char-to-be-numerically-outputted-from-function-call) doesn't work.

Comment: @dyp, that does not seem very convincing.

Comment: Well, right now for all streams we have an `operator<<` taking a `charT` and an `operator<<` taking a `char`. That's going to be tricky to do as members since `charT` can - and often is - `char`.

Comment: The whole design doesn't really convince me :D -- but yes, that raises the question why the other inserters aren't free functions either..

Comment: For chars, it is indeed defined as non-member operator function - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2

Comment: @T.C. There's even a specialization `template<class traits>
basic_ostream<char,traits>& operator<<(basic_ostream<char,traits>& out,
char c);
` for this case

Comment: @T.C. I think your explanation makes the most sense. All free functions have this issue. They're `char`-inserters or `char*`-inserters, in various flavours.

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/1996/N0918.pdf

Comment: http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/1996/N0880.pdf "9.2 Library WG" mentions the issue solved by N0918. So if there's a paper containing the rationale for the solution, it should be somewhere around this time span.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The set of inserters for `std::basic_ostream` includes partial specializations for inserting `char`, `signed char`, `unsigned char` and such into `basic_ostream<char, ...>` streams. Note that these specializations are made available for `basic_ostream<char, ...>` streams only, not for `basic_ostream<wchar_t, ...>` streams or streams based on any other character type.

If you move these freestanding templates into the main `basic_ostream` definition, they will become available for all specializations forms of `basic_ostream`. Apparently, library authors wanted to prevent this from happening.

I don't really know why they wanted to introduce these specializations on top of the more generic

```
template<class charT, class traits>
basic_ostream<charT,traits>& operator<<(basic_ostream<charT,traits>&,
                                        char);
```

inserter, but apparently they had their reasons (optimization?).

The same situation exists for C-string inserters. In addition to the more generic inserter

```
template<class charT, class traits>
basic_ostream<charT,traits>& operator<<(basic_ostream<charT,traits>&,
                                        const char*);
```

the library specification also declares more specific

```
template<class traits>
basic_ostream<char,traits>& operator<<(basic_ostream<char,traits>&,
                                       const char*);
```

and so on.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your answer: There's a generic `template<class charT, class traits>
basic_ostream<charT,traits>& operator<<(basic_ostream<charT,traits>& out,
char c);
` function template that works fine for `wchar_t`.

Comment: @ dyp: Yes, but at the same time they felt the need to introduce the dedicated specialization for inserting `char` values into `char` streams. I don't really know why, but the library spec says such specialization exists.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if that "specialization" prevents an overload resolution issue.

Comment: @AnT, *Apparently, library authors wanted to prevent this from happening.* is most likely the reason. It will be interesting if someone involved in the development of the libraries can throw some light on the subject.

Answer (score 6):

One reason is following the general C++ advice of preferring non-member non-friend functions to member functions. This is item 23 in Scott Meyer's *Effective C++*. This is discussed in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989734/effective-c-item-23-prefer-non-member-non-friend-functions-to-member-functions).

Comment: Good to mention this. This rule-of-thumb does not seem to be known by many programmers, leading to god object or object orgy antipatterns...

Comment: Right, I usually think about it in terms of coupling or with avoiding that everything that one could do with some class becoming overly coupled. I'd rather that enhancements by done via the public interface so I don't have to worry about how so many function could potentially change state the object (affecting class invariants), even if `const` member can help as well. This also makes it easier to partition functions into various more focused headers files.