# function for intersection of 2 lines design

Tags: c++, oop, linear-algebra

I have class Line, which represent 2 dimensional line. It has function for checking if 2d point lie on this line.

```
class Line
{
    private:
       float a,b,c: //line coefficients
    public:
    bool checkPointOnLine();
    .....
}
```

now I have to check find point of intersectionof 2 lines. I'm wondering if it is better to put new member function in class Line  like

```
class Line
{
    private:
       float a,b,c: //line coefficients
    public:
    bool checkPointOnLine();
    Point getIntersectionPoint(const  Line& line);
    .....
}
```

or to use non member function

```
Point getIntersectionPoint(const Line& l1,const Line& l2);
```

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989734/effective-c-item-23-prefer-non-member-non-friend-functions-to-member-functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although to a large measure this is a matter of preference, a static or non-member function approach is slightly more preferable because of symmetry.

When two calls

```
a.someFunction(b)
```

and

```
b.someFunction(a)
```

always return the same result, a symmetric function

```
someFunction(a, b)
```

is more intuitive.

Note that since an intersection may not exist (for parallel lines) or have an infinite number of points (for two identical lines) returning a `Point` is not ideal. You would be better off returning a pair of `Point` and some indicator of its validity, for example

```
enum LineIntersectionKind {
    Valid
,   Empty
,   Infinite
};

pair<Point,LineIntersectionKind> getIntersectionPoint(const Line& l1,const Line& l2);
```

Comment: I agree with your answer but in such a case I have to private members in this function (line coefficients) I have to use friend for example or to put getters for them. Or maybe the best is to put static function for this.

Comment: @VladimirYanakiev An approach that does not require friendship is to make the function static in the `Line` class, i.e. `static Line::getIntersectionPoint`.