# Why std::make_unique instead of std::unique_ptr::make?

Tags: c++, c++14, smart-pointers

Why did C++ adopt free functions for:

```
std::make_unique(...);
std::make_shared(...);
```

instead of using static member functions:

```
std::unique_ptr::make(...); // static
std::shared_ptr::make(...); // static
```

?

Comment: @M.M Thank you, Captain Obvious. The question is: WHY there is no `make` function.

Comment: @M.M where I wrote "why you use"?

Comment: I just love how three under-caffeinated developers fumbled their answer, myself included. Good morning everyone ;)

Comment: @vladon: TBH, I don't think that there is a good reason - that's just how it was proposed. Your proposed syntax is slightly longer and also is different from the existing `make_pair` and `make_tuple`

Comment: @VittorioRomeo there is the same for `make_pair` and `make_tuple`: why not `std::pair::make` and `std::tuple::make`?

Comment: @vladon because *these* ones deduce the pair/tuple's content from their arguments, and that's their whole rationale -- you can write `std::pair<int, float>{42, 3.14f}` :)

Comment: @vladon: why not `create_pair` or `tuple::build`? It's just how it was proposed and everyone was OK with it. I think you're looking too much into this

Comment: Try it. Write a template class that provides a member function, then write code that uses it and **actually compiles** and you'll see why.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

TL;DR: Static member functions always have access to private data but free functions only have access to private data when explicitly marked as `friend`. The choice to implement these functions as free functions (with a small number being implemented as friend functions) isn't a random historical artifact, but is a deliberate decision to improve encapsulation while having a consistent naming scheme for all of the `std::make_x` functions.

---

There are [many standard factory functions](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=std%3A%3Amake_) in C++:

```
std::make_pair
std::make_tuple
std::make_unique
std::make_shared //efficiency
std::make_exception_ptr //efficiency
std::make_move_iterator
std::make_reverse_iterator
std::make_error_code
std::make_error_condition
//And several more are proposed for C++17
```

For all of the above, the `make_x` function can be implemented correctly using only the public interface of `x`. In the case of `make_shared` and `make_exception_ptr`, the most efficient implementation would require access to the internal data of the `std::shared_ptr` or `std::exception_ptr`. All the others can be implemented using just the public interface with zero performance penalty.

Implementing these functions as non-friend free-functions reduces the amount of code that has access to the private internals of the object ([a desirable property](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/084.htm), since when less code has access to private data, there are fewer places that have to be audited for operations that violate the invariants of the object, and fewer places that potentially need to be changed if the internals of the object change).

If `make_shared` were the only similar factory function, it might make sense for it to be a member function, but since the majority of such functions are not required to be `friend` functions to operate efficiently, `make_shared` is also implemented as a free-function, for the sake of consistency.

This is the correct design, as if static member `make` functions were consistently used, then in every case apart from `make_shared` and `make_exception_ptr`, the member function would unavoidably have excessive access to the private data of the `x` object. With the standardised design, the small number of `make_x` functions that need access to private data can be marked as `friend`, and the rest respect encapsulation correctly by default. If a non-member `make_x` were used in some cases and a static member `make` in others, the standard library would become inconsistent and more difficult to learn.

Comment: Pretty sure there are more than 4: http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=make_

Comment: @Caleth: Yes, I am updating the answer now. The expanded list only makes the point clearer.

Comment: +1: [Effective C++ Item 23: Prefer nonmember nonfriend functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989734/effective-c-item-23-prefer-non-member-non-friend-functions-to-member-functions). This is just Encapsulation 101.

Answer (score 17):

**Consistency**.

I don't think that there is any compelling reason to have the `::make` syntax instead of the current one. I assume that `make_unique` and `make_shared` were preferred to a static `::make` function to stay consistent with the existing `std::make_pair` and `std::make_heap` functions, that existed pre-C++11.

---

Note that `std::make_pair` has a big advantage: it automatically deduces the types of the resultant pair from the function call:

```
auto p0 = std::make_pair(1, 1.f); // pair<int, float>
```

If we had `std::pair::make`, then we would have to write:

```
auto p1 = std::pair<int, float>::make(1, 1.f);
```

which defeats the purpose of `make_pair`.

---

- I therefore assume that `make_unique` and `make_shared` were chosen because developers were already used to `make_pair` and similar functions.
- `make_pair` was chosen instead of `pair::make` for the aforementioned benefits.

Comment: but the question is not about `make_pair` but about `make_unique` which anyway you have to specify the return type both in `unique_ptr<T>::make` and `make_unique<T>`

Comment: @DavidHaim consistency of similar things is a valuable property

Comment: @Vittorio Romeo, but you write about the advantage of `make_pair` over `std::pair<T>::make` where it has nothing to with `make_unique`

Comment: @DavidHaim: it has - `make_pair` was chosen in the past over a possible `pair::make` due to argument deduction. `make_unique` was *probably* chosen later over `unique_ptr::make` because `make_pair` already existed.

Comment: Also, at least some of the committee prefer non-member non-friend functions over members: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/084.htm

Comment: @DavidHaim It makes the standard library easier to learn if everything behaves as you expect it to and so given that `std::make_pair` already existed, users of the library come to *expect* creator functions to be stand alone functions beginning with `std::make_...`.

Comment: -1 There is a compelling reason and it is non-member non-friend functions  are increasing encapsulation. Mankarse answer is superior IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

There is not a concrete reason other than convention alone -
a static-class function can do everything a global function can do (functionality wise).
C++ prefers global functions (for utility functions) which contained inside a defined namespace.
Other programming languages (such as Java) prefer static public functions, as global functions are not supported.

this is not new to `make_***`, other examples exists:

`std::this_thread::XXXX` instead of `std::thread::XXXX_current`
 although it might had sense to put function which relates to the current thread of execution as static functions inside `thread` class, they are made global inside `this_thread` namespace.

also, we could have something like `std::container::sort` which `std::container` is a helper class for containers, but we have `std::sort` instead.